# git impossible to push after add

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

Ok, I've a trouble that I'm not able to fix since some week.
I use git (on github) to store my projects. Recently I've added some new files in it without problems, but, when I use "git push" I've a timeout error.

I use Ubuntu 12.04, with ssh (default) and https.

So, I decide to make fresh copy of the depo (git clone).
After this I modify an existing file, commit it and push it ... with success !

So, I add the others (in the new copy), commit them and push them. And the  problem come again: unable to push
Here is the console output:

```
time git push
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 16.61 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
^C

real    7m59.383s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.004s
```

I really don't understand what i doing wrong here.
I in other depo, same problem, but my collaborator don't have any troubles.

I remove git, and reinstall it with no change.

If you have any idea to solve this.

### edit 1

```
git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:Krozark/projet_compilation.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Krozark/projet_compilation.git (push)
```

## edit: Solution

```
sudo ifconfig [wlan0] mtu 1460 (lower than 1500)
```

Comment: Show the output of `git remote -v`. It looks like a network timeout, but without the URI of the remote there is nothing much SO can do to help. Also, can you `git fetch` from that remote?

Comment: try now. Github looks working ok again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I saw this exact same problem that a colleague was having and it was network related with SSH, we were using a VPN connection at the time and it ended up being the network MTU setting being too high (it was 1492 if I remember correctly), we tinkered around with smaller values until it started working. So something to do with network packet splitting it seemed.

Not sure if this is the case for you however although it doesn't hurt to try change your network MTU to a lower value to see if it works.

Of course if it's an issue on Github's side, this won't be a factor (the fact you can create a new repo and push up leads me to believe it's not MTU related).

Comment: I do this: sudo ifconfig wlan0 mtu 576, and it solve it. Thx!

Comment: I would try setting your MTU to be as high as possible (you can't exceed 1500 - it's the maximum ethernet limit), but you might be able to go around 1460 or so without issue. It's better to have as high an MTU as you can get, but keep things functional.

Comment: I will try other valu, but i start with a very small to test your solution. 1460 is ok. My default value was 1500.

Comment: +1. I mentioned VPN in my answer, but this answer is much more specific.

Answer (score 4):

As you've suggested that pinning your MTU has been effective at alleviating the problem, I'd recommend a more targeted solution.

```
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT 1 -o wlan0 -d 207.97.227.239 \
    -p tcp --dport 22 --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1420
```

This hijacks the initial TCP negotiation with the server (only for SSH on github.com's IP), and forces the MSS to 1420. This is effectively the same as setting the MTU, but is more selective. It's good in some situations where you can't easily save the MTU change, and would need to re-apply it each time the interface was taken down/up.

The MSS needs to be 40 less than the MTU to allow for the 40 byte TCP header + the data segment (MSS is Max Segment Size).

The most common reason for needing to do something like this (ie, getting MTU below 1500), is VPNs and tunnels. PMTU is meant to solve this, but it fails in far too many situations, leaving you to manually need to adjust the MTU for certain paths. Using the iptables rule allows you to tailor your traffic differently for different problem paths, rather then forcing you to set you MTU to the lowest common denominator for all paths. The problem with doing that is that you slowly diminish your effective bandwidth by increasing your header to data ratios.

Comment: Does explain in more detail what the root cause is +1

Answer (score 2):

If the local is fine (ie your git and ssh are working fine), then it should be an issue on the  remote side:

Check [GitHub Status](https://status.github.com/messages).

#### Today

> 3:22 UTC We are investigating issues with one of our fileservers, a small number of repositories are unavailable.

It could be possible you are affected by the current recurrent access issues mentioned on GitHub.

---

Or it is a connection issue (like a [missing VPN route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/757462/6309))

Comment: If it isn't the case, one other instance of timeout could be http://blog.barbarycodes.com/2011/01/16/fix-for-%E2%80%9Cgit-push%E2%80%9D-timeouts-on-new-repository/: `git push --no-thin`. But this isn't *exactly* your case.

Comment: It could be the source, but apparently not, because i try just now.

Comment: I try git push --no-thin, no changes.

Comment: @Krozark I didn't know this, but **[`git push --no-thin` won't actually work until git 1.8.5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18756313/6309)**.